# how to install ffmpeg on macbookpro osx 10.8.3

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I have downloaded FFMPEG from this link http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html under FFmpeg Mac OS X Builds section, all builds come with .7z extension i need help how to configure it on my machine.

Comment: A .7z file format is a compressed file. Since it contains a prebuild package, just extract it to a folder using software like [KeKa](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/) and you can run FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to install FFMPEG is to use Homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

the above command will install Homebrew and then to install FFMPEG use the following command

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Cheers